# Best way to create multi-step form with data saved to user account for later updating?

Tags: forms, plugin-gravity-forms

I'm attempting to set up a fairly long multi-part form (~50 questions, a few questions per page) with conditional logic. I'd like to offer registered visitors the ability to save their data between each page/step and give them the option to return later to finish.

I have Gravity Forms and thought that might work, but it sounds like this isn't functionality they offer yet.

Does anyone have any advice/suggestions on other form plugins or code which might meet these requirements? Thanks in advance for all your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are working on a custom theme, I believe it is easier to be done with a page template and WordPress's wp_ajax function.

The form can be included in the page using `<?php get_template_part('form','0f-50-question') ?>`.

Here is the pseudo code for the form

```
<form id="quite-a-long-form" action="<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>" method="post" class="form" >
    $step = $_GET['step']
    if $step = 1
        //first section of question
        echo <label>
        echo <input>
        echo <label>
        echo <input>
    else if $step = 2
        //second section of question
        echo <label>
        echo <input>
        echo <label>
        echo <input>
    else if $step = 3
        //third section of question
        echo <label>
        echo <input>
        echo <label>
        echo <input>
    // just repeat for all sections
    endif
    <input type="Submit">
    <?php wp_nonce_field('input-answer','security-code-here'); ?>
    <input name="action" value="input-answer" type="hidden">
</form>
```

And for the php that will process the file

```
function process_add_transfer() {
    if ( empty($_POST) || !wp_verify_nonce('security-code-here','add_transfer') ) {
        echo 'You targeted the right function, but sorry, your nonce did not verify.';
        die();
    } else {
        // do your function here 
        wp_redirect($_POST['_wp_http_referer'].'?step='.$index_of_the_next step);
    }
}
```

Hope this help